# Posso utilizar a função dd() em produção?

Tags: php, laravel, return

Eu criei uma função que é chamada em outra classe pra realizar uma tarefa durante uma requisição num *Controller* da minha aplicação.

Eu coloquei um `return` nessa função para interromper sua execução em uma situação específica. Só que após esse `return`, a função principal do *Controller* continua rodando. Eu utilizei então a função `dd()` do Laravel para interromper toda a execução nessa situação mas, eu acho que essa função é utilizada somente para *Debug*.

Vocês utilizam essa função também para situações específicas em códigos que estão em Produção ou somente para *Debug* mesmo?

Essa a função na qual inseri o `dd`, que está dentro de outra classe:

```
public function verificaItens($shipmentPed,$AuxPedido){
    $pieces = explode("-", $shipmentPed);
    $tagSearch = TRIM($pieces[0]).' - '.TRIM($pieces[1]);

    $tag = \App\pedidosretira::where("shipment_tray",strtoupper($tagSearch))->first();      

    if(!isset($tag->num))
     return response("Informação de Retirada '".$shipmentPed."' não 
     encontrada na base local da integração.", 203);

    $this->num = $tag->num;
}
```

Abaixo, a linha que chama a função dentro do Controller:

```
$AuxPedido->verificaItens($pedido->shipment,$AuxPedido);
```

Comment: O return deveria parar a execução do seu controller. Você pode [edit] sua pergunta e incluir o trecho do código do controller? Sobre o dd() tens razão, é mais para debug. Recomendo você retornar algum tipo de mensagem para o usuário, pois só um `return;` pode não fazer sentido como um retorno.

Comment: Ocorre que eu chamo essa função dentro de um Controller mas, ela está em outra classe, não está dentro desse Controller. Por issoa função do Controller continua rodando depois desse return. Editei a pergunta e inseri o código.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

É normal o *controller* não encerrar a execução, pois ele em si não retorna nada. O *controller* executa `verificaItens` mas não faz nada com a `Response` criada.

Isole no contexto do *controller* sua lógica para trabalhar com as *responses*, e na sua lógica de negócio implemente só suas regras de negócio.

Por exemplo, atualize seu *controller* e sua lógica de negócio para algo próximo a isso:

```
public function codigoController() {

    // alguma coisa

    // atenção para a negação no começo do if
    if (!$AuxPedido->verificaItens($pedido->shipment) {
        return response("Informação de Retirada '{$pedido->shipment}' não encontrada na base local da integração.", 203);
    }

    // segue o fluxo positivo

}
```

No código do seu método, tente deixar mais coeso o que aquele método deve fazer, evitando passar valores não usados naquele método:

```
// $AuxPedido não é usado dentro do método, e é estranho um método receber o próprio objeto
public function verificaItens($shipmentPed) 
{
    $pieces = explode("-", $shipmentPed);
    $tagSearch = trim($pieces[0]).' - '.trim($pieces[1]);

    $tag = \App\pedidosretira::where("shipment_tray",strtoupper($tagSearch))->first();

    // assumindo que esse é um valor numérico, retorna verdadeiro se for maior que zero, 
    // ou falso se for 0 ou nulo. 
    // Não vai funcionar se for uma string (sempre vai voltar true)
    return (bool) $tag->num;
}
```

> Vocês utilizam essa função também para situações específicas em
>   códigos que estão em Produção ou somente para Debug mesmo?

O `dd()` é usado para fins de *debug* mesmo. Não é recomendado utilizá-lo para encerrar um fluxo. Recomendo a leitura de como funciona o [ciclo de requisições](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/lifecycle) do Laravel para entender o que acontece com seu código até chegar no seu *controller*.

Comment: Bacana. Interessante mesmo tratar a resposta da função no Controller. Vou fazer assim.

Answer (score 2):

@Kênia em produção geralmente **APP_ENV**=production e APP_DEBUG=false sendo assim tanto exceções quanto a utilização do dd são desviados para o log \storage\logs\laravel.log, pois ao utilizar o dd a interrupção gera **http 500 Internal Server Error**, para o usuário em produção aparece uma tela padrão do laravel sem mostrar os dados.

Caso queira ver o dd teria que alterar os parâmetros citados. Porem para cenário de produção não é aconselhado pois ao deixar os logs e debug aparecendo na tela, eles trazem informações que podem favorecer alguém mal intencionado. O ideal para produção seria o log no arquivo assim somente você poderia ver:

```
Log::debug($message);
```

Caso queira mostrar uma mensagem para o usuário isso deve ser retornado para o controle, e do controle para a view.

Comment: Muito didático. Não sabia que o dd ia para o log na situação apresentada.